# Can IntelliJ refactor properties (get/setters) to fields?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Let's say I have a bunch of classes implemented javabean-style and I want to get rid of getters/setters and just have public fields instead. Any way to effectively refactor that using IntelliJ 14 while not breaking compilation?

Example - before:

```
class Baratheon {
    private String stannis;
    public String getStannis() {
        return stannis;
    }
    public void setStannis(String stannis) {
        this.stannis = stannis;
    }
}

class Lannister {
    public Lannister() {
        Baratheon b = new Baratheon();
        b.setStannis("dead");
    }
}
```

--after:

```
class Baratheon {
    public String stannis;
}

class Lannister {
    public Lannister() {
        Baratheon b = new Baratheon();
        b.stannis = "dead";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? There are good reasons to control access to field values and languages with sensible, native support for allowing access to fields *also* give you the means to revert to getter / setter without breaking your API. In Java that's not possible - once someone has access to your field there's no taking it back without changing the API.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that debate and just focus on the features of intellij

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The obvious steps involved in your refactoring are:

1. make field public, retain accessors.
2. change client code to access field directly rather than via accessors.
3. remove accessors.

You *could* leverage the 'inline...' refactoring in intellij (Ctrl + Shift + n) to help with step 2.

I don't think there's a single refactoring tool in intellij which does the whole job, bearing in mind that it's only really possible if the entire affected codebase is in a single project. You *could* look into writing a [plugin](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/index.html) which does the job.

Comment: Didn't know of the inline-refactoring. That one does most of the job when selecting 'Inline all invocations and remove the method (n occurences)'. Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

1.make access to the field the same as that of getter
2.right click on getter then choose refactor / inline... ( in Android Studio )